# pytesseract not keeping leading zeroes when using image_to_data()

Tags: python, dataframe, python-tesseract

I'm using pytesseract to process the following image:

[image: 03]

When I use the `image_to_string()` function

```
config = "--oem 3 -l eng --psm 7"
pytesseract.image_to_string(potential_image, config = config)
```

I get the correct "03" output. However, when I use the `image_to_data()` function

```
predict = pytesseract.image_to_data(potential_image, config = config, output_type="data.frame") 
print(predict)
predict = predict[predict["conf"] != -1]

try:
    detected = " ".join([str(int(a)) if isinstance(a, float) else str(a) for a in predict["text"].tolist()])
    confidence = predict["conf"].iloc[0]
    print("Converted detected:", detected)
    print("with confidence:", confidence)                  
except:
    pass
```

I get:

```
   level  page_num  block_num  par_num  line_num  word_num  left  top  width  height       conf  text
4      5         1          1        1         1         1     4    4     25      16  95.180374   3.0
Converted detected: 3
with confidence: 95.180374
```

Where the leading 0 is not preserved, and the result is a float that I later have to convert to an int / string. Is there a way to preserve the text output so that it is the same as `image_to_string()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `data.frame` as the output type, use a regular Python dictionary:

```
pytesseract.image_to_data(image, config = config, output_type = pytesseract.Output.DICT)
```